# Does Ubuntu prevent customization of pynotify notifications?

Tags: customization, notify-osd, libnotify

Does anyone know why I'm unable to change notification settings using pynotify?

I can create a notification, modify it (for example so it should show up in the middle of my display), and tell it to display, but it still shows up in the upper-right corner.

And if this is configurable, anyone know how to do so?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, using fluxbox.

Here is the function that displays the notification:

```
def displayNotification(msg):
  """Display the given notification."""
  if not pynotify.init("hey"):
    displayError("Unable to initialize notification library...")

  n = pynotify.Notification("Hey!", msg)
  n.set_hint("x",400)
  n.set_hint("y",400)
  n.set_timeout(2 * 3600 * 1000)
  if not n.show():
    displayError("Unable to show notification...")
```

This worked exactly as expected under Arch Linux, before I switched to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notify-OSD does not allow for customization by default (extremely frustrating I know) - but it is so by design. You would need to use another notification method to get the same positioning and other options.

Comment: So pynotify falls under notify-osd?

Comment: from what you describe, yes.

Comment: pynotify is used for communicating with the desktop notification system. If you are running notify-osd (default in ubuntu) then it will use that. If you stop notify-osd and start another notification system (e.g. notification-daemon (the old one) or xfce4-notifyd) then pynotify will use that.

Comment: @RoryMcCann: Lol, I'm aware of that, I was answering his question based on what he asked.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Oh yes, but in case other people are reading this and think the problem is with pynotify per se